# Cordova File Plugin, none of the callbacks are firing

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

Using http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file and plugin installed = org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"

I capture a picture and am trying to convert it to base64. The picture location returned (var path below) is "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ECB406E6-E361-46AA-9282-FEEBDAC170DF&ext=JPG"

At first from the documentation it looked like all I needed is:

```
   // Convert to image URL base64
   var fileReader = new FileReader();
   fileReader.onloadend = function (data) {
        console.log(data.target.result);
   };

   fileReader.readAsDataURL(path);
```

The code executed but the callback never fired! I then dug around and added a bunch of other fileReader options... exactly zero of which actually execute. Same behavior on both iOS and Android

```
        fileReader.onload = function (data) {
            console.log("onload", data);
        };


        fileReader.onerror = function (data) {
            console.log("error!", data);
        };


        fileReader.onloadstart = function (data) {
            console.log("onloadstart", data);
        };
```

I'm not getting any JS errors, but I'm also not getting any console output.

1) Why are the Cordova File FileReader() callbacks not firing?

**Update**

I tried using ngCordova's file plugin as well, http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

```
$cordovaFile.readAsDataURL('assets-library://asset/', 'asset.JPG?id=ECB406E6-E361-46AA-9282-FEEBDAC170DF&ext=JPG')
            .then(function (success) {
                // success
                console.log("ng success", success);
            }, function (error) {
                // error
                console.log("ng error", error);
            });
```

With that I receive the following error:

> Error in Success callbackId: File1336724899 : TypeError: undefined is
>   not a function (evaluating 'e.getFile')

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to use a regular URL, not an asset library URL.  To confirm I'd probably try to use an image on a website to see if it will load that...

Comment: Thanks @Mike, 1) why wouldn't I get an error then? 2) if I pipe the path to an img's ng-src or something it works perfectly fine 3) I do need to access that image to send though, any suggestions on how?

Comment: I don't know about the lack of errors - maybe it gets stuck resolving the URL.  Anyways, if you're using the cordova photo plugin, you can use the FILE_URI option to get a "normal" file url.

Comment: I'm using cordova camera preview plugin, since I need the live preview, it then captures the image. Strange it's so awkward to access the path itself...

Comment: the camera plugin natively copies the raw photo data from the asset library into the user directory to support the FILE_URI option.   you might have to do something similar...

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through numerous SO posts and forums regarding this behavior. The `Error in Success callbackId:` issues occurs on my iOS version of the application we are building, but not Android. Upon further investigation (with logging behavior in ngCordova source code itself) I found that `assets-library://asset/` translates to a `NATIVE_URI` in Cordova, which is a `FileEntry` object in the W3 File System API spec that is designed from: [FileEntry Interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/#the-fileentry-interface)

Using a `FILE_URI` (which in my case, I was using the cordova camera plugin and was easily configurable), I noticed that I was now using a `DirectoryEntry` object, and provided the `getFile` function I was looking for: [DirectoryEntry Interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/#the-directoryentry-interface)

TL;DR: Try using `FILE_URI` (file://) instead of `NATIVE_URI` ('assets-library://asset/' for iOS) to get `DirectoryEntry` objects that provide a `getFile` function.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently the same problem with moveFile function, in my case I was making a mistake. In the function moveFile, I was sending the directory with the file name, in the moveFrom parameter in my service. The correct way is set only the directory.

```
function moveFile(moveFrom, currentFileName, moveTo, newFileName) {
    return $cordovaFile.moveFile(moveFrom, currentFileName, cordova.file.dataDirectory + moveTo, newFileName);
}
```

Cordova file plugin could return an invalid directory error.

See the complete issue in ng-cordova repository

https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/1160